# Android auto scroll activity content on long press

Tags: android, android-listview

I am newbie to android  my activity implemented a drag and drop in list view but when my list is full its not displaying last record on the screen as length of the list record is bigger then screen size .. so when I tried to drag and drop my first record at the end of the list 
I can select first record but I cant scroll down to the last record .. I need to implement when I select my first record and drag it toward down list ll automatically scroll down toward end of the list and vice versa hope I make some thing clear to you .. if still there is any ambiguity let me know 
Thank

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `listview.smoothScrollToPosition(position)` inside your drag and drop function. Define the position of dragged element and if needed use `smoothScrollToPosition` method.

Comment: @llya Blok  i tried this code but its not fullfiling my requirements because I want to move listview with the drag shadow, I want to say when user hold the top most element and move the element towards  the last position meanwhile the list automatically scroll upwards and vice versa